# セルの従業員数をテキスト型から数値型にしたいです

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

画像のように「870名」「565人」などと書かれたセルの中から数値部分だけを抜き出し、数値型に変換して元のセルにそれが反映されるようなGASマクロを組んだつもりですが、正規表現で数値を抜き出す構文でエラーが発生しています。

正規表現の書き方が誤っているのか、それとも一旦別のメソッドを使って文字列操作を行う必要があるのか？
または、セルの指定を一つずつ行わないとMatchメソッドは使用できないなどの仕様なのか？
教えていただけないでしょうか。

この構文でエラーが発生しています。

```
empcell.match( /\d/g ).value
```

**従業員数を書いたセル:**

[image: 従業員数を書いたセル]

```
function employee(){
//functionはGAS（Google　Apps　Scriptという、グーグルが開発したプログラミング言語これのこと）の関数名を宣言する意味の言葉  
//employeeとは従業員数を数値型に変えるための関数（値を入れる箱のようなもの、変数との違いは関数の中には変数を入れられること）

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//varは変数の名前を宣言（変数とは値を入れる箱、関数の内部で使う）
//SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();は、スプレッドシートアプリをGAS内で使うための宣言、変数に入れることで、これをsheetという言葉に置き換えて短くできる

var empcell = sheet.getRange('L2:L1000');
//empcellの中に従業員数セルを指定して、その値を入れる
//変数名sheetでスプレッドシートアプリを使う宣言を行い、getRange()というメソッド（これを使えばこうなる、というあらかじめ約束された道具のようなもの。）で従業員数のセル列名を指定

empcell.match( /\d/g ).value;
empcell.copyTo(empnum, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
//.match( )は、（）内の条件に適したデータを取り出すメソッド、 （/\d/g）は正規表現と呼ばれる「いくつかの文字列を一つの形で表現できる」方法、\dは数字のみという意味で、gはそのセル内すべての文字列を指す
//empcellの箱の中に、従業員数のみにした値を入れる

    }
debugger;
```